# How to copy defined columns with defined number of rows from one Excel file to another

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I am new to VB and I am going to use it for Quick Test Pro (QTP). I am having a problem to copy data from one Excel to another Excel file with specific rows and columns. Here is the scenario:

1. I have one Excel file with more than 20 rows. Let say 100 rows.
2. I need to copy the first row, then the 2nd to 20th rows, then save it to a different file.
3. I need to copy the first row, then the 21st to 41st rows, then save it to a different file.
4. Then same thing for the rest. Until there is NO value on the last row.

I need to copy the first row, because this is where the title/header is that I need.

So far, this is what I did. But it only copies the single column and NOT the columns that I want:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook1 = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Report\CMaxx_File1.xlsx")
ObjExcel.Visible = True
Set objWorkbook2 = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Report\CMaxx_File2.xlsx")
objWorkbook1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A21").Copy
objWorkbook2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A21").PasteSpecial 
objWorkbook2.Save
```

Comment: We can help you, but we won't do your task for you. You said: _I am having a problem_ - What problem exactly? Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29242690/edit) your question and add what you have tried so far. Please also take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions.

Comment: Could it be you have a list in at least one of the sheets? Are the column headers normal cells, or are they list column headers?

Comment: Hi The BlastOne, The header like ClientName, AcctNum, TypeCode and etc. Under each header there are values and I need to capture the header and the next 20 rows. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Still not the best way to do it but I tested it and it works.  Make sure you change the variables to match your paths, also the column range

This will take a spreadsheet with more than 20 rows and create a new spreadsheets (as many as required) with 1 row header an d19 rows data (20 rows total)

```
  allRowsWorkbook = "C:\XXXXX\stack\x\Original.xlsx"
   newXLS = "C:\XXXXX\stack\x\New_sheet_20_rows"

    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    'Open the workbook that has all the rows
    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(allRowsWorkbook)

     rowCnt = 2    
     LineCnt = 0
     intRow = 2
     bookCnt = 1

     'Spreadsheets that will be created

     xlsName = newXLS & bookCnt & ".xlsx"
     createNewBook(xlsName)


     Do Until objExcel.Cells(intRow,1).Value = ""

        for lineCnt = 0 to 20 
         Wscript.Echo "CN: " & objExcel.Cells(intRow, 1).Value
         intRow = intRow + 1
         lineCnt = LineCnt + 0
         rowCnt = rowCnt + 1
        next 
        LineCnt = 0
        wscript.echo "Out"
        bookCnt =  bookCnt + 1
        xlsName =  newXLS  & bookCnt & ".xlsx"
      wscript.echo    xlsName 
        createNewBook(xlsName)
     Loop

     Function createNewBook(xlsName)
     Set objExcel2 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
         Set objWorkbook2 = objExcel2.Workbooks.Add()
      objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:F1").Copy
      objWorkbook2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:F1").PasteSpecial

      objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & rowCnt & ":i" &(rowCnt +20) ).Copy
      'sleep was added to make sure copy had tinme to comlete
       wscript.sleep 1000
      objWorkbook2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:i2").PasteSpecial


             objWorkbook2.SaveAs(xlsName)
             objWorkbook2.Close(xlsName)

     End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Bagger for your time in helping me to address this issue. I tried running the code and I am getting error "Object Required: objWorkbook" I think you forgot to declare. I tried to use "Set objWorkbook = objExcel2.Workbooks.Add()" but I am getting this error "Object Not Supported" Again Thank you.

Comment: You need to change the workbook path to your location

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open _
      ("C:\xxxx\stack\x\sample2a.xlsx"). 
and 
 xlsName = "C:\xxxx\stack\x\samplesss" & bookCnt & ".xlsx"

If you set the paths correctly it should work

Comment: Hi Bagger, Sorry for being stupid :-) but is this the excel that I need to split to 20 rows?  Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open _ ("C:\xxxx\stack\x\sample2a.xlsx"). IF Yes, then this is what I did Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open _
  ("C:\Documents and Settings\xxxxxx\My Documents\Documents\Cmaxx Report\CMaxx_File1.xlsx") then for the xlsName, is the excel should be existing on NOT?

Comment: It is almost working but I got an error object required on the wscript.echo and wscript.sleep. I tried to declare by using this "WSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")" but no success. Again Thanks alot for helping me with this. I hope you can help me to fix the error. I also tried commenting out all the lines with WScript, but it it is copying all the data from the excel NOT the 20 rows.